# Filter on condition, take n with circuit breaking

Tags: javascript, typescript

What is the best way to filter by a condition and take first n results in an array with circuit breaking?

Think a search filter on a predefined list of items:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].filter(x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x < 4;
}).take(2) === [1, 2];
// 1
// 2
// true
```

the `take` function does not exist as the filter function only returns an array and i want the circuit breaking functionality for the stream. is there a composition using functional methods that would produce this?

i.e.

```
// would not process 3, 4, 5, or 6 as the circuit would break at 2.
take([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], x => x < 4, 2) === [1, 2]
```

The function should also stop if no more elements remain. i.e.

```
take([1, 2, 3], x => x < 4, 4) === [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Use the indices: `filter((x,i) =>  i < 2 && x < 4)`.

Comment: that would still iterate through all elements regardless, i'm sure there is a smarter solution that stops as soon as the max index/limit is reached.

Comment: you could use a for loop

Comment: So, it depends on what do you consider *smart*. A simple `for` loop with `return` would do that. But I reckon nowadays nobody considers a `for` loop good/smart enough...

Comment: i was hoping for a solution that looked neater. it seems strange one doesn't exist with a quick search. thought it would have a common convention solution to it. I'm mocking up a for loop now but would be interested if someone had a functional solution to the problem.

Comment: `_take(arr, predicate, limit) {
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length && results.length < limit; i++) {
      if (predicate(arr[i])) {
        results.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return results;
  }` using typescript

Comment: you do have a good point there @GerardoFurtado, if it aint broke... technically speaking, the function i wrote is pure as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @GeraldoFurtado for the philisophical point. For loops are smart because they do their job, they're just old so get ageist remarks from all the hipster functional programmers like me.

```
let take = (arr, predicate, limit) => { 
  const results = [];
  const arrLength = arr.length 
  for (let i = 0; i < arrLength && results.length < limit; i++) { 
    if (predicate(arr[i])) { 
      results.push(arr[i]); 
    } 
  } 
  return results; 
}
```

Regardless, I would be keen on knowing anyone else's solutions to this problem, but this seems pretty performant to me... maybe a prototype shim solution?

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant only thing i could refactor is arr.length. although i feel the performance gain is very minimal from that anyway.

Comment: When the array grows up to near by million rows, the performance improvement will not be not trivial anymore. If you set both the lengths in a constant, and the array happens to be few scopes outer, the time used to retrieve the length becomes significant.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this in a fairly elegant way using either generators or observables.

#### Generators

I have actually developed [a little npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/func-generators) specifically for this purpose.

Using that package, and Ramda, you can get your desired result like this:

[Try it in RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/t3lnujc05ggs)

```
const { genTake, genFilter, genFrom, genToArray } = require("func-generators");
const { compose } = require('ramda');

const probe = x => (console.log(x),x);

const firstTwoUnderFour = compose(
    genToArray,
    genTake(2),
    genFilter(x => probe(x) < 4),  //  genFilter(x => x < 4),
    genFrom,    
);

console.log(firstTwoUnderFour([5,6,7,1,6,8,2,9,10,5]));  // [1, 2]
```

I have added a probe to the filter predicate to show which elements it's processing. You can see from the console output that it stops as soon as it reaches `2`.

Basically, what it's doing here is:

1. Make a generator function from the original array (`genFrom`)
2. Transform that generator function to one that only produces the values that match the predicate (`genFilter(x => x < 4)`)
3. Transform that generator function to one that only produces the first two values from the one in step 2 (`genTake(2)`)
4. Converge the generator function from step #3 into an array of values (`genToArray`)

The more generalized `take` from the answer you posted could then be written like this:

```
const take = (arr, predicate, limit) => compose(
    genToArray,
    genTake(limit),
    genFilter(predicate),
    genFrom,
)(arr);
```

This even works on an infinite sequence of values:

[Try it in RunKit](https://runkit.com/jlrishe/5db29291b9d645001dd2c85b)

```
const { genTake, genFilter, genInfinite, genToArray } = require("func-generators");
const { compose } = require('ramda');

const firstFiveMultiplesOf125 = compose(
    genToArray,
    genTake(5),
    genFilter(x => x % 125 === 0),
);

console.log(firstFiveMultiplesOf125(genInfinite()));
```

One last thing to note: I'm using Ramda's compose for readability here, but you could just as well nest these function calls instead, or call them one-by-one:

```
const result = genToArray(gnTake(5, filter(x => x < 4, genFrom([1,2,3,4,5,6]))));

// or...

const gen = genFrom([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
const first2 = genTake(2, genFilter(x => x < 4, gen));
const result = genToArray(first2);
```

---

#### Observables

One slightly more heavyweight approach is to use Observables, such as the [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) library:

[Try it in RunKit](https://runkit.com/embed/6z7lyen0meiz)

```
const { from } = require("rxjs")
const { take, filter, toArray } = require('rxjs/operators');

const probe = x => (console.log(x),x);

from([5,6,7,1,6,8,2,9,10,5]).pipe(
    filter(x => probe(x) < 4),
    take(2),
    toArray(),
).subscribe(xs => console.log(xs));    // [1, 2]
```

You can see here too that it stops checking elements from the array as soon as it reaches `2`.

Comment: I haven't looked into generators recently, I feel like this is probably the solution I could investigate if I really wanted to be 'cool'.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `for ... of` loop with a lazy evaluation and exit if the result array has a length of two.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = [];

for (let item of array) {
    if (item < 4) if (result.push(item) === 2) break;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If *good old for loop* does not bring aesthetic satisfaction, you may use (in somewhat unnatural way) one of high-order functions with *embedded circuit breaker* if you're addict to them as much as I am:

```js
const arr = [2,6,9,8,4,3,7,5];

const res = [];

//first 3 items less than 8
arr.find(n => n<8 ? (res.push(n), res.length==3) : false, res);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/)!

```
take(filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], x => x < 4), 2)
```

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking for. It iterates all elements of the array: `const probe = x => (console.log(x),x); _.take(_.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], x => probe(x) < 4), 2);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const take = (array, predicate, length) => {
  let result= []
  let i = 0
  while (i <= array.length && result.length < length) {
    if (predicate(array[i])) {
      result.push(array[i])
    }
    i++
  }
  return result;
}

const test1 = take([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], x => x < 4, 4)
console.log(test1)

const test2 = take([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], x => x % 2 === 0, 5)
console.log(test2)
```